# Webcam not identified on Lenovo IdeaPad Y580

Tags: 13.04, hardware, webcam, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Lenove IdeaPad Y580 and Google Talk to make a video call only to find out that the camera is not working. This problem did not occur when running Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10.

What I did was ran: `gstreamer-properties` and this is what I got:

> (gstreamer-properties:6510): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkDialog.has-separator
>
>
>   (gstreamer-properties:6510): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkDialog.has-separator
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'artsdsink'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdsink'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sunaudiosink'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'glimagesink'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sdlvideosink'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'v4lmjpegsrc'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'qcamsrc'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'v4lsrc'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdmon'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sunaudiosrc'
>   gstreamer-properties-Message: Error running pipeline 'Video for Linux 2 (v4l2)': Cannot identify device '/dev/video0'. [v4l2_calls.c(493): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
>   system error: No such file or directory]

According to Lenovo Support (http://support.lenovo.com/en_CA/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT073649) this computer uses an AzureWave webcam.

### Additional information

> uname -r
> 3.8.0-19-generic
>
> lsusb
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>   Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e042 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
>   Bus 002 Device 007: ID 13d3:5162 IMC Networks
>
> lspci
>   00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
>   00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
>   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
>   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
>   00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
>   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
>   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
>   00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
>   00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
>   00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
>   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
>   00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
>   00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GTX 660M] (rev a1)
>   02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 08)
>   03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 (rev c4)
>   04:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
>   04:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
>   04:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 30)
>   04:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller (rev 30)

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering whether you compiled the alx module yourself and installed it before the webcam issue began, because that's what's going on on my end. The default alx module in 13.04 for the AR8161 Ethernet card doesn't work for my Y580 and when I make my own from compat-drivers and install it, the webcam stops working. alx somehow screws with another module, uvcvideo, which is needed in order to access the camera feed. After I install alx myself, uvcvideo is no longer loaded at startup and I can't load it manually, if I try "sudo modprobe uvcvideo" I get something along the lines of 'uvcvideo' Invalid argument

It turns out that the makefile that was in the tar.gz I downloaded from a link included some other modules in the make sequence (videodev and something other from v4l2...) So, I didn't install just alx, I actually overwrote some other modules which were working just fine and in the end, it was the unintentionally built videodev that conflicted with uvcvideo, so I solved the problem by installing the 3.9 kernel and modifying the makefile so it would build only the alx module and everything went great :) Now I've got both a working Ethernet card and a working webcam.